# Content script doesn't work in Edge extension

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge-extension

The extension is supposed to hide the video player of Netflix movie, but it doesn't have any effect after execution. The code for var hidePlayer can successfully hide the video player if it's executed in f12 tool.

content.js

```
console.log("hi");
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Hello World",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Simple Microsoft Edge Extension",
"author": "Hrishikesh Kale",
"icons": {
   "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
   "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
   "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
   "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "20": "icons/icon_20.png",
        "25": "icons/icon_25.png",
        "30": "icons/icon_30.png",
        "40": "icons/icon_40.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Hello World"
},
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
],
"minimum_edge_version": "37.14316.1000.0",
"background": {
"page": "background.html",
"persistent": true
  },
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "css" : ["css/light.css"],
  "js": ["js/content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}]
}
```

background.js

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var hidePlayer = "(function () { "
                     +"    var panel =  document.getElementById('appMountPoint');"
                     +"    if (typeof (panel) != 'undefined' && panel != null) {"
                     +"        if (panel.style.display === 'none') {"
                     +"            panel.style.display = 'block';"
                     +"        } else {"
                     +"            panel.style.display = 'none';"
                     +"        }"
                     +"    }"
                     +"})();";
    browser.tabs.executeScript({
        code: hidePlayer
    });
});
```

background.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I've attached the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jogyypbs0z0civ/edge-extension-sample.zip?dl=0). To reproduce the bug, please play a Netflix movie in the Edge browser before loading the extension.

Comment: Have you ever tried directly running the code of `makeItGreen` in F12 tools? since it would be a little complicated for us to debug --- we have to register netflix first.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Specifically, there is no description of what it is supposed to do, and what does happen (and how that is a problem/not what was expected).

Comment: @HaibaraAi sorry I can't find where to run the script in edge's f12 tool.

Comment: @JasonGeng, At least for me, Edge's F12 Developer Tools shows an entry line at the bottom of the Console tab, which can be used to run commands/scripts. In case it was not clear, you should only be trying to run the actual content script code: `(function () { var panel =  document.getElementById('appMountPoint');if (typeof (panel) != 'undefined' && panel != null) {if (panel.style.display === 'none') {panel.style.display = 'block';} else {panel.style.display = 'none';}}})();`, not the whole extension.

Comment: Thanks. The code works in f12 tool after I execute it. Then why it doesn't work in the extension?

Comment: If you are going to include jQuery, please have it as a separate file. Don't mix in the minimized jQuery with your own code. You can include multiple files in a single `content_scripts` `"js"` array (e.g. `"js": ["js/jquery.js","js/myContent.js"]`)

Comment: @HaibaraAi There is an one month free for Netflix account. Can you register an account? I tested the code in f12 and it works. The problem is it doesn't work in extension.

Comment: *Please* do not load jQuery into **every** http and https page (`content_scripts` with your `matches`) unless you **have** to.  jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. This is a significant burden with which to saddle *every single page*. While It is possible you really *need* to load jQuery, what is more likely is that you are doing so for the convenience of saving a couple/few hundred characters in your own code by not writing your code in vanilla JavaScript. If that is the case (we have no way to know), doing so is a *very* poor trade-off from your user's point of view.

Comment: @Makyen I didn't use jQuery in this small sample. There is indeed a content script file but I didn't use it yet. Thanks for your advice. I hope firstly I can make clear why the current code doesn't work.

Comment: You need to include at least your *manifest.json* and *background.html* files in the question. Without them, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @Makyen Is that ok to only add the text of manifest.json and background.html? It'd be too long if I add text of all files.

Comment: The point is that a [mcve] should be the *minimum*, but *complete*, amount of code that is necessary to duplicate the issue. Without a [mcve] that duplicates the problem *in the question itself* (not just linked, links can go bad), a debugging question is off-topic. In this case, that probably only means a *manifest.json* with the `content_script` entry edited out (verify you  still have the problem once edited), the *background.html*, and *background.js*. If you desire, you can include the icons, but I normally don't.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: The other things that need to be in the question are the desired behavior (i.e. a description of what it is supposed to do) and the specific problem (i.e. what it is doing wrong, or what it is not doing that you expect it to do). In other words, "can't work for Netflix movie" just does not give us enough information as to what the problem is.

Comment: @Makyen The extension can't be loaded in to edge after I edited out content_scripts in manifest.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In testing your code I found Edge's operation to be intermittent. "Reloading" the extension did not appear 100% effective. Displaying the background page sometimes dropped into a mode where Edge would open up the window for the extension's background page, but the window was blank. I ended up removing the extension and restarting Edge many times. My impression is that Edge extension support is not really ready for prime time (i.e. it is buggy and needs development work).

I found operation of your extension to be more consistent when using a `background` `scripts` entry rather than a `page` entry. Strangely, after using the `script` entry returning to using the `page` entry started to work.

I changed your *manifest.json* to the following:

```json
{
    "name": "Hello World",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Simple Microsoft Edge Extension",
    "author": "Hrishikesh Kale",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
        "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "20": "icons/icon_20.png",
            "25": "icons/icon_25.png",
            "30": "icons/icon_30.png",
            "40": "icons/icon_40.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Hello World"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "minimum_edge_version": "37.14316.1000.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["js/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```